# Проверка состояния программы в linux через код на C/C++

Tags: c++, linux, c

Всем привет, необходимо проверять состояние программы на вычислительном узле. Допустим на моем компьютере лежит программа, как мне проверить кодом на C/C++ ее состояние - активна, не активна. Возможно ли как то получить pid процесса программы, через файл или что то в этом роде,спасибо за ответ)

Comment: директорию `/proc` смотрите

Comment: спасибо за наводку, а вот хочу спросить в Linux у каждого файла есть свой индексный дескриптор файла, возможно ли как нибудь узнать какие процессы используют этот файл через него ?

Comment: вопрос не понятен

Comment: @DanBit, кто использует файл? -- посмотрите на fuser или lsof

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу так: программно пробегаю файлы в /proc они называются типа 4556 или 1345 названия состоят из чисел. В этих папках есть файл comm в нем лежит имя программы которая породила процесс, сравниваю имя с искомой программой, если такое имя  в этих папках в файле comm есть, значит такая программа сейчас активна.

Comment: Если бы вы более внятно сформулировали вопрос, вам сразу же посоветовали бы уже готовую утилиту ([ps](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)), вывод которой (вмете с grep) обычно используют для подобных целей

Comment: @avp, в любом случае это не всегда работает (программа может подменить *отображаемое* имя, так что тут надо знать заранее, что мы ищем). И второе, `pgrep` куда практичнее.

Comment: Условно, моя программа просит имя программы и проверят если такая